# How to use <version>tag value from pom.xml in logback.xml

Tags: maven, logback

I want to print the version of my project at the first of every my logfiles.
and for that i need to use my pom.xml  tag. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a little configuration.

If using Logback configuration file (it will use the `logback-test.xml` or `logback.xml` found on the classpath), you can make use of Maven filtering. In your Logback config file, configure a pattern with the `${project.version}` variable, such as:

```
<pattern>${project.version}|%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

And configuring Maven resource filtering to include and filter your Logback config, For example:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/logback-config</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>logback-test.xml</include>
          <include>logback.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

When you build your project, Maven will output a file in `target/classes/` (or the configured project build directory) with `${...}` tokens replaced with actual value. For example with `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`:

```
<pattern>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT|%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

You'll also need to make sure your application with Logback uses this file (i.e. it is found on the classpath). That will depend on how you package and run your apps, but as the file will be in the project build directory chances are it will be done automatically. If you provide details on how you want to run your app I'll try to help.